# Preventing malicious HTML injections using htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html, security, hyperlink, code-injection

I have been referring to a certain website about how htmlspecialchars is used to prevent malicious code injection, but I am now more confused than before. Assume that a hacker enters the following into a textbox:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://nastywebsite.com&quot;&gt;Nasty Website&lt;/a&gt;
```

(If the above entities are decoded, they will read: Nasty Website)

Let's assume that the hacker has inserted the above code into the FIRST_NAME textbox of an online survey, so the malicious code will be associated with the 'first_name' attribute. And let's say the owner of this online survey wants to protect against HTML injection by having the following code:

```
<?php
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $first_name = htmlspecialchars( $first_name );
  echo $first_name;
?>
```

This is where I get confused. The hyperlink that will be echoed (as I understand it) is "Nasty Website". That means that an innocent user can still click on that hyperlink and he will unsuspectingly download malicious software on to his device. So what is the point of the htmlspecialchars function?? Surely if the string was filtered by the htmlspecialchars function, as the above code suggests, the user would have seen the harmless text:

```
           &lt;a href=&quot;http://nastywebsite.com&quot;&gt;Nasty Website&lt;/a&gt;
```

instead of the hyperlink. And if the user DID see the entities instead of the hyperlink, he would not have been able to download malicious codes. I don't get it. Does the user see the ENTITY or the HYPERLINK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't escape your string, the user will see:

[Nasty Website](http://google.com)

If you escape, this is what he will see:

```
<a href="http://nastywebsite.com">Nasty Website</a>
```

Html renderers decode entities as characters and do not interpret them as valid tags.

If you want to not allow html tags in your inputs you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags).

Comment: Waldson, thank you for much for that. You explained an issue succinctly in 6 lines that some websites I referred to could not explain properly in 60 lines!